# CLion IDE, inconsistent output

Tags: c, io, output, clion

I have been learning and coding C language on CLion IDE. I wrote a program to calculate my course grade but there are always inconsistent outputs. For example, sometimes outputs are executed correctly, sometimes CLion's terminal displays anything on the screen. However, when I execute my program with native terminal, it always works properly. What is wrong with CLion?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
double essay_calc(double grd1, double grd2, double grd3)
{
    double sum1, sum2, sum3, result;

sum1 = (100*(grd1) / 22.0);
sum2 = (100*(grd2) / 22.0);
sum3 = (100*(grd3) / 22.0);

result = ((sum1*1.10) - sum1 + (sum2*1.15) - sum2 + (sum3*1.20) - sum3);

return (result);
}
double presentation(double pre1, double pre2)
{
    double sum1, sum2, result;

sum1 = (100*(pre1))/23.0;
sum2 = (100*(pre2))/40.0;

result = ((sum1 + sum2)/2)/5;

return (result);
}
double hw(double grd1)
{
    return ((grd1*15)/100.0);
}
int main(void)
{
    double ess_grd1, ess_grd2, ess_grd3, pre_grd1, pre_grd2, hw_grd;
    double total, essay, present, howork;

printf("Enter 3 essay grades: ");
scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &ess_grd1, &ess_grd2, &ess_grd3);
printf("\nEnter 2 presentation grades: ");
scanf("%lf %lf", &pre_grd1, &pre_grd2);
printf("\nEnter 1 HW grade: ");
scanf("%lf", &hw_grd);

essay = essay_calc(ess_grd1, ess_grd2, ess_grd3);
present = presentation(pre_grd1, pre_grd2);
howork = hw(hw_grd);

total = (essay + present + howork);

printf("\nEssays: %.2f\n", essay);
printf("Presentations: %.2f\n", present);
printf("Homeworks: %.2f\n", howork);
printf("Total: %.2f\n", total);

if(total < 70)
    printf("You have to get %.2f points from final exam to pass\n", 70 - total);
else
    printf("Your grade is already over C\n");


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seeing how the correct output is from a later time, are you sure that isn't the result of a cached (c)make build? It seems extremely unlikely to me that some printf's just get ignored or the program exits before calling them, *without* setting an error exit status...

Comment: I always run after building my code and output can be different, certainly not stable. Also automatically reload Cmake on editing is enable.

Comment: You are expected to post text as text, not images and/or links!

Comment: Just to explain my problem better, I used images of outputs. If they are totally not necessary, I can remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current version of CLion has several issues with terminal output, the [CLion 2016.1.2 Release Candidate](http://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2016/04/clion-2016-1-2-rc/) is supposed to fix these.

Comment: Thanks for information, I supposed that I broke CLion by configuring.